# internet explorer compatibility with angular material

Tags: angular-material

I am working on MEAN stack with **angular material design**. After testing on chrome & firefox, every functionality including flex & offset etc is working perfect. but in internet explorer, nothing is working as it is supposed to.

My question is, how to make angular material compatible with IE 10 & IE 11?

Answer (score 12):

Angular Material is targeted for all browsers with versions n-1; where n is the current browser version.  IE 10 is no longer supported.

Edge seems to work well with material, but IE 11 still has some discrepancies.  I get around these layout issues by simply adding a few CSS rules to elements that aren't displaying correctly while making sure they don't affect my Chrome / FF layouts.

Also the way you nest your divs; layout rows, input containers, etc, can have an undesirable effect in IE 11.  Trial and error worked best for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid angular-material if your main targets are internet explorer, but instead use [Angular-Materialize](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/) library which is a add-on (directives) library for http://materializecss.com/ that works pretty much with every modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

As for Angular 5 you can uncomment **imports** in **polyfills.ts** to deal with IE.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is referring to the former Angular (aka AngularJS 1.x)

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular 8, I got the Angular Material Datepicker to work in IE by doing the following:

- **Removed** everything that had to do with moment.js and the material moment adapter. (Uninstalled it)
- Imported *MatNativeDateModule* in app.module.ts
- Set the appearance attribute to "legacy" in the html, like this:

  `<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">`